# Setter sets value for every object in class

Tags: java, setter

I have a program that takes students' names and grades as user input and then performs some operations on them, which are irrelevant for the scope of the question. The code is as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Student {
// Four attributes that define Student
private String name;
private double points;
private int startYear;
private int[] grades;

public Student(String name, double points, int startYear, int[] grades) {
    this.name = name;
    this.points = points;
    this.startYear = startYear;
    this.grades = grades;
}
//Constructor. Everyone starts with 0 points and this year

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); //Create scanner
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of students:");
    int count = sc.nextInt(); // Number of students
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of grades:");
    int count1 = sc.nextInt(); // Number of grades
    Student students[] = new Student[count]; // Create array of student objects based on previously entered value
    int[] temp = new int[count1]; // Temporary array for storing grades entered
    for (int i = 1; i < count + 1; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of student " + i);
        String name = sc.next();
        students[i - 1] = new Student(name,0.0,2018,temp); // Creating student object
        System.out.println("Please enter grades of  " + name);
        for (int k = 0; k < count1; k++) {
            int personal_grades = sc.nextInt();
            temp[k] = personal_grades; //filling the temporary array
            //System.out.println(grades.length); //for debugging

        }
        students[i - 1].setGrades(temp); //transferring from temporary array to student object array
        students[i-1].printGrades();

    }
    System.out.println((students[0].name));
    System.out.println((students[1].name));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(students[0].grades));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(students[1].grades));
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        System.out.println("Grades of  " + students[i].name + " are:");
        //students[i].printGrades();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        System.out.println("Average of  " + students[i].name + " is:");
       // students[i].average();
    }
    int passed=0;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        if(students[i].average()>5.5)
        {
            passed++;

        }

    }
    System.out.println(passed+" students passed!");


}

public void setGrades(int[] temp) {

        this.grades = temp;


}

public int[] getGrades() {
    return grades;
}

public void printGrades() {


        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(grades));

    }

public float average (){
    int k = 0;
    int sum=0;
    float average=0;
    while (k < this.grades.length) {
        sum=sum+this.grades[k];
       k++;

    }
    average = sum/(float)this.grades.length;
    System.out.println(average);
    return average;
}
}
```

The problem I am having with the code is as follows: the setter method appears to set the values for all of the objects that were ever created. Take this test run as an example:
[image]

You can see that the grades for the last student entered appear in every student's record. I have debugged and found that it is the `setGrades` method that causes this. However, I am using the `this` keyword - why does it set the value for all the objects then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the

```
int[] temp = new int[count1]; // Temporary array for storing grades entered
```

inside the outer `for` loop, otherwise all created `Student`s will have a reference to same grades array and all will end up with the grades of the last student.

Answer (score 0):

Move the array (`temp`) holding the grades inside the loop where you create individual Students

```
for (int i = 1; i < count + 1; i++) {
    ...
    int[] temp = new int[count1];  //The array holding the grades must be *specific* for each student

    students[i - 1] = new Student(name, 0.0, 2018, temp); // Creating student object
    ...
    students[i - 1].setGrades(temp); //transferring from temporary array to student object array
    students[i - 1].printGrades();

}
```

In your original code, you are using just one array i.,e `temp` was pointing to the same array all the time. After you finish initializing the first Student, when you loop populating the grades for the second student, you are mutating (or modifying) the *same* grades array created for the first student.

Answer (score 0):

Note how both `Student`'s constructor and `Student::setGrades()` get `grades` by reference.

This means that for each `Student`'s instance, its `grades` field points to the parameter that was received during its initialization.

However, you only initialize `temp` once and therefore all the instances point to the same grades array. Once this array is changed, calling `student.printGrades()` will print the shared array's contents.

This can be solved by initializing `temp` on every iteration, before creating a new `Student` instance; Or by copying the array **by value** inside `setGrades()` method:

```
public void setGrades(int[] temp) {
    this.grades.clone(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using the same array for all the grades of everyone.

Moving
`temp = new int[count1];` inside the first loop should fix it